# Iterate polygon column in ArcGIS model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a polygon with many columns. I want to convert into raster. I could do it one by one. But I want to iterate for each column of the polygon by model builder or any other way. Here you can see the attached table of the polygon. For example I want to make one raster for Abst85, another one for Abst91, .....Then save them in separate

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Do the values in each column identify a set of different polygons or do they identify the same? Suggest you update your question with a few images?

Comment: i have edited my question , could you please check again

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can be easily automated in model builder as there is no iterator for fields within a dataset.

You can achieve what you are asking with the following python script.

```py
import arcpy

# Input layer
fc = r"C:\Scratch\sdr_subnational_data_dhs_2008.shp"

# Create a list of field names
fieldList = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

# Remove any non numeric or system fields
fieldList.remove('FID')
fieldList.remove('Shape')

# Set output workspace and cellsize
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\scratch"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
cellsize = 0.018

# Main loop
for fn in fieldList:
    rn = "ras_" + fn + ".tif"
    arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(fc,fn,rn,cellsize)
```